# Filter data received from HTTP request

Tags: c++

So in my c++ program i create a socket then download file from my web server (website) which retrieves a http response (using `recv`) then store response in `char` buffer, in this question let's say the buffer identifier is something like `httpbufff`, if i take `httpbufff` and `cout` it, it will look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 08:52:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.16
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

Website content test
```

My question is, is there a way to extract `"Website content test"` from my `char` buffer `httpbufff`?
I was thinking about using `strtok` but that doesn't seem like a good solution in my opinion.
thanks!

Comment: Use `string::find` or `strstr` to find the buffer position of 'Website..' ?

Comment: An HTTP response has two parts: the header and body; the parts are separated by an empty line.